# Can't figure out the correct payload to BatchGetItemCommand in aws-sdk 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I can't figure out what the payload should be for `BatchGetItemCommand`. I've read the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write-batch.html) and looked at the Typescript typings.

This is the table:

```
    StagesTable:
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:service}-${opt:stage}-StagesTable
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: color
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: stage
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: color
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: stage
            KeyType: RANGE
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

I am trying to retrieve the two rows where the color is blue or green. This is my payload

```
  const payload = {
    RequestItems: {
      tableName: {
        Keys: [
          {
            color: { S: 'blue' },
          },
          {
            color: { S: 'green' },
          },
        ],
      }
    }
  };
```

I get

> (node:79852) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationException:
> The provided key element does not match the schema
> at deserializeAws_json1_0BatchGetItemCommandError (.../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:589:24)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Since your schema is

```
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: color
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: stage
            KeyType: RANGE
```

you need to specify both keys

```
 const payload = {
    RequestItems: {
      tableName: {
        Keys: [
          {
            color: { S: 'blue' },
            stage: { S: 'A' },
          },
          {
            color: { S: 'green' },
            stage: { S: 'A' },
          },
        ],
      }
    }
  };
```